# What's the difference between the following two XSLT expressions?

Tags: xslt

What is the difference between these expressions?

`<xsl:text>someValue</xsl:text>`

`<xsl:value-of select="'someValue'"/>`

And which to use?

Comment: The latter is a confusing version of the former, making one think it selects a node value when it does not. While the former is a longer version of just `someValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `<xsl:text>someValue</xsl:text>` and `<xsl:value-of select="'someValue'"/>` create a text node with the contents `someValue` so there is no difference and if you want to output a literal text it is up to you which form you prefer. Of course in general `value-of` and its `select` attribute allow you the use of an XPath expression of any type, so in case you don't want to output a string hard coded in XSLT you would use `value-of`.

Answer (score 1):

`<xsl:value-of select=""/>` element is used to extract the value of a selected node.

The `<xsl:text>` element is used to write literal text to the output. This element may contain literal text, entity references, and `#PCDATA`.

Note that in your exemple, both will return the same as you specify to select the text 'someValue', but I tought it would be nice to tell you the difference between both.

Comment: `#PCDATA` includes literal text and entity references. Maybe checkout the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Creating-Text) instead of w3schools.